# Регулярное выражение для замены XXXXг. на XXXX г., чтобы отлепить "прилипший" год?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите регулярное выражение, которые бы искало в тексте прилипшую к цифрам года (две или четыре цифры) букву г с точкой ("г.") и разделяло бы и их пробелом.

Желаемое поведение:

```
1956г. -> 1956 г.
56г. -> 56 г.
12345г. -> 12345г.
45г -> 45г
```

Comment: Думаю, для поиска можно что-то такое использовать `^\d{2,4}[г]\.` https://regex101.com/r/sNlKqj/1

Comment: @Alexshev92 `{2,4}` ведь еще и 3 включает?

Comment: @gil9red, ну да. Тогда наверно, как-то так `^((\d{2})|(\d{4}))[г]\.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Лучше для этого использовать [неразрывный пробел](https://unicode-table.com/ru/00A0/) - его код `\xA0` (`\u00A0`):

```js
console.log(
`1956г. -> 1956 г.
56г. -> 56 г.
12345г. -> 12345г.
45г -> 45г`
.replace(/\b(\d{2}|\d{4})(г\.)/g, "$1\xA0$2")
)
```

Comment: А почему `\xA0`, а не пробел?

Comment: @gil9red, это неразрывный пробел - с ним не будет между годом и "г." переноса строки.

Comment: @gil9red в iOS это тоже "неразрывный пробел"? )

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, я ожидал что будет или пробел или `&nbsp;` :) А [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB) рассказано что `&nbsp;` это и есть `\xA0`, да и по правилам проблем нельзя ставить в определенных случаях чтобы не было переносов

Comment: @xhr, ну должен быть :) Всё-таки символы везде одинаковые. Некоторые языки запись `\xA0` могут не поддерживать, а полную юникодную `\u00A0` - поддерживать, но тут тебе виднее. Ну или можно просто неразрывный пробел прям символом поставить.

Comment: @gil9red, `&nbsp;` - это его html-обозначение. Ему не место в нормальных строках, потом что строки при выводе положено экранировать. Надо ставить сам символ. Вообще, есть подозрение, что правильнее ставить узкий, но я обычно не настолько заморачиваюсь с типографикой.

Comment: @Qwertiy может записать решение с обычным пробелом, а как опцию указать, что можно использовать неразрывный пробел? (хотя может этих комментов уже достаточно) Так как запись его везде различна, а вопрос все таки задан в общем виде )

Comment: @xhr, ну я думаю можно догадаться поставить пробел вместо кода символа? Я бы мог вообще в замене неразрывный пробел поставить как есть и никто бы даже не подумал, что он там стоит))

Comment: @xhr, дополнил ответ.